# What's wrong with my simplification of these exponentials?

Tags: proof-explanation, exponential-function, fake-proofs

The question states:

> Simplify $2^{\sqrt2}$

I tried doing:
$$2^{\sqrt2}=2^{(2^{\frac{1}{2}})}$$
$$=(2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=4^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=2$$
$$=2^1$$

Clearly this is ridiculous as I've just "proved" $2^{\sqrt2}=2^1$. Yet my proof seems quite convincing to me. Where did I go wrong? I tried debugging by trying a similar technique on $2^4$ and it worked fine.

$$2^{4}=2^{2^{2}}$$
$$=(2^2)^{2}$$
$$=4^{2}$$
$$=16$$
$$=2^4$$

Comment: Your second equality is false. RHS is $2^{1}$ and LHS is $2^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: $a^{b^c}\neq(a^b)^c$.

Comment: People tend to overlook the fact that iterated exponentiation is *not* associative.  As a matter of definition, $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$.

Comment: Anyway, I think $2^{\sqrt2}$ is already as simple as it's going to get. I don't know what someone had in mind when they asked for it to be simplified.

Comment: The second example works because of $2^2=2\cdot 2=4$

Comment: Did you ever find out what the answer to "Simplify $2^{\sqrt2}$" was supposed to be, John?

Answer (score 5):

Because $x^{(y^z)}$ (like you did in the first example) does not mean $(x^y)^z$. It works in your second example because by chance $2^2=2\times 2$.

We say that the exponentiation does not have the *associative property*.